# list comprehension with generator

Tags: python

I used generator to generate some lists. However, it doesn't work like what I expected. I first used numgen1 to to generate the list while it doesn't work properly. And I switched to numgen2 which can gave me what I want properly. But both the numgen1 and numgen2 are basically the same (at least I think), why do they behave so differently? May anyone give me some explanations?

```py
def numgen1(start, end, delta):
    curr=start 
    while curr[1] < end[1] or curr[2]<end[2]:
        yield curr
        curr[2] += delta


print 'Output1: ', [ i for i in numgen1([1,1,1],[1,1,5],1)]

def numgen2(start, end, delta):
    curr=start 
    while curr[1] < end[1] or curr[2]<end[2]:
        yield [curr[0], curr[1], curr[2]]
        curr[2] += delta


print 'Output2: ', [ i for i in numgen2([1,1,1],[1,1,5],1)]
```

Here are the outputs.

```
Output1:  [[1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 5]]
Output2:  [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4]]
```

**Follow up question:**

After reading the answer from unutbu, I write one more generator that is used to test what unutbu said. But the generator doesn't behave as unutbu said. I am so confused about whether a generator is yielding a pointer or a copy of the value.

```
def numgen3(start, end, delta):
    curr=start 
    while curr<end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta

print list(numgen3(1,10,1))
```

Here is the output.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

This time I try to generate some numbers instead of some lists. But why aren't all the elements in the list 9? I didn't create a new number, I just yield the same number (curr). I expect the result of numgen3 should be similar to that of numgen1.

Comment: You can replace `[i for i in generatorFunction()]` with `list(generatorFunction())` btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curr` is a list. `curr[2] += delta` is modifying the list *in-place*.

When you yield `curr`, you are yielding the same list over and over. 
When you print `Output1` you are seeing this same list being printed many times.

When you yield `[curr[0], curr[1], curr[2]]` you are generating a new list. Thus, when you print `Output2`, you see different values.

---

Notice how modifying `curr` affects **all items** in `result`, because `result` is a list containing 3 items, each the same list `curr`:

```
curr = [0,0,0]
result = [curr for i in range(3)]
print(result)
# [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

curr[2] = 100
print(result)
# [[0, 0, 100], [0, 0, 100], [0, 0, 100]]
```

---

You could "fix" `numgen1` by yielding `list(curr)` since `list(curr)` returns a new list with the same elements as in `curr` (i.e. a "shallow copy"):

```
def numgen1(start, end, delta):
    curr=start 
    while curr[1] < end[1] or curr[2]<end[2]:
        yield list(curr)
        curr[2] += delta

print 'Output1: ', [ i for i in numgen1([1,1,1],[1,1,5],1)]
```

yields

```
Output1:  [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4]]
```

---

Regarding `numgen3`:

```
def numgen3(start, end, delta):
    curr=start 
    while curr<end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta

print list(numgen3(1,10,1))
```

It helps to make a mental distinction between mutable and immutable values. A list is mutable, numbers such as `ints` are immutable.

Lists are containers. You can mutate its contents without changing the reference to the container. Thus `curr` is a list, `curr[2] += delta` mutates the *contents* at index 2, but `yield curr` yields the very same list.

In `numgen3`, `curr` is an immutable `int`. `curr += delta` assigns `curr` to a new immutable `int`. It no longer references the same object. `yield curr` yields that value. Those different values are accumulated in the list comprehension, and thus you see the result containing different values.

---

Here is another perspective on what it means to modify a list *in-place*: The modification is done *in-place* if the contents of the list change, while the memory address of the list itself does not change.

`id(obj)` returns the memory address of the object `obj`. Notice that modifying `curr[2]` does not change the `id` of `curr`:

```
In [162]: curr = [0,0,0]

In [163]: id(curr)
Out[163]: 196192940

In [164]: curr[2] += 1

In [165]: curr
Out[165]: [0, 0, 1]

In [166]: id(curr)
Out[166]: 196192940
```

Compare that with what happens when you increment a variable assigned to an `int`:

```
In [191]: curr = 1

In [192]: id(curr)
Out[192]: 150597808

In [193]: curr += 1

In [194]: id(curr)
Out[194]: 150597796
```

Here, `curr` is not being modified in-place. `curr` is simply being redirected to reference a new value at a new memory address.

Comment: You mean that I am yielding same pointers which all point to the same variable (curr) in numgen1, while yielding different pointers in numgen2?

Comment: Essentially yes, except that Python does not have pointers. You are yielding *objects*. When you `yield curr`, you are yielding the very same object each time. In between `yields` the object is getting modified, but by the time it is printed, all you see is the state of the object after all the modifications have been done.